# Unable to decode strange Xml file

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have to parse some xml output (from a request to a web site) like below bellow. They are partly in English, partly in French. I am not able to decode and to print (on screen, on file) the French accents like 'é' or 'à'

When I use `decode('utf-8')`, I have a wrong result like '`Ã¨`'. I am using python 3.3.

```
b'Extr\xc3\x83\xc2\xaamement fort et incroyablement pr\xc3\x83\xc2\xa8s</title><originaltitle>Extremely Loud And Incredibly Close</originaltitle><year>2011</year><runtime>0</runtime><directors><director>Stephen Daldry</director></directors><plot>Oskar Schell, 11 ans, est un jeune New-Yorkais \xc3\x83\xc2\xa0 l\'imagination d\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9bordante. Un an apr\xc3\x83\xc2\xa8s la...</plot></movie></results>\n'
```

Comment: What platform (operating system) are you using?

Comment: Working on linux (ubuntu)

Comment: Did you mean your last edit it seems to removed the xml declaration - but you should edit the xml so it is readable

Comment: You should accept the answer (below the score of the answer).

Answer (score 5):

The byte string you pasted is double encoded,

```
byteStrInYourQuestion.decode('utf-8').encode("ISO-8859-1").decode("utf-8")
```

should work.